# JwtTokenFilter null pointer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using JWT in my backend app and I have the following classes to achieve it.

JWTTokenFilter: validating the token

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Autowired
JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);

    try {
        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
}
```

JWTTokenProvider: Creating and handling the token in this class.

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

@Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret}")
private String secretKey = "secret";

@Value("${security.jwt.token.expire-length:3600000}")
private long validityInMilliseconds = 3600000;

@Autowired
ModelMapper modelMapper;

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Override
@Autowired
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
}

public String createToken(String username, List<Role> roles) {
    Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
    claims.put("roles", roles);
    Date now = new Date();
    Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliseconds);

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setIssuedAt(now)
            .setExpiration(validity)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretKey)
            .compact();
}

Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
    User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(getUsername(token));
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", user.getAuthorities());
}

String getUsername(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
}

String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return bearerToken.substring(7);
    } else return null;
}

boolean validateToken(String token) throws Exception {
    try {
        Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token);
        if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new Exception("Expired or invalid JWT token");
    }
}
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.demo.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    ...
```

How can I handle null pointer and I think it is related to Autowiring the provider component.

Comment: which line is 22 in JwtTokenFilter class? Did you try to debug?

Comment: how do you instantiate this JwtTokenFilter class? Manually?

Comment: String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest); //line 22 @pvpkiran

Comment: I debugged and jwtTokenProvider object is null how can it be null?